# Showing a fixed point is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $r$ be a fixed point in $R^{(k)}$ and defined $f: R^{(k)} \rightarrow R^{(k)}$ by $f(x)=x+r$

Then prove that $f$ is continuous.

How do I approach this question? I am confused as to what topic exactly this falls under. Does think fall into vector-valued functions or differentiation? What is the mechanism to approach this question?

Comment: It's very confusing to call $r$ a "fixed point," since that usually means something else. What do you know about continuity? Do you know how to prove any function is continuous?

Comment: This is essentially true because translations of open sets remain open.

Comment: Yes I usually know how to prove something is continuous but I am confused of the notation R^(k). The space is throwing me off quite a bit and as such I am unaware of how to proceed.

Comment: Its k-dim euclidean space.  Nothing exotic.

Answer (score 0):

First we shall prove $ f^i:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f^i(x)=x+r^i$, where $r^i$ is constant, is continuous.

$$|f^i(x)-f^i(y)|=|x-y|$$ hence $f^i$ is continuous.
Now for $ r,x\in \mathbb R^k $ ,$r=(r^1,r^2,......,r^n)$ and $x=(x^1,x^2,......,x^n)$ .
Hence, by the continuity of $ f^i:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ each components of f are continuous.hence f is continuous.